# Android/Eclipse : 9-patch image and black lines

Tags: android, eclipse, nine-patch

I have created a 9-patch image with draw9patch, but the black lines still appear on the devices when I launch the application while they don't appear in the  graphical layout. I tried to do Eclipse -> Project -> Clear but it didn't work
[image]

Comment: If the 9patch is not constructed properly then it will show like this. Try draw9patch and again create a 9patch image

Comment: But how could I know if it constructed properly?

Comment: Make sure you have specified all the four corner lines

Comment: I didn't draw lines at right and left, just in top and bottom, but it shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: Make sure you have correct file extention xxx.9.png

Comment: You should really read the guide to making nine patch images http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: Can you post the 9-patch file on here so that we can take a look at how you've edited it?

Comment: save your file as something.9.png

Comment: Ok, so my problem was that I thought the right and bottom lines were for stretching areas which is not the case + i didn't precuse a left line (only a top line) for my image so maybe eclipse did not understand it was a 9 patch. Thank you very much for your help all!